# Can Office.js Web Add-ins be Used in Mobile Devices' Word Apps?

Tags: ios, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have developed an Office.js web add-in for Microsoft Word, and it works flawlessly in the desktop version of Word for Windows and macOS. However, when I tried to use the same add-in in the mobile versions of Word for iOS and Android, I couldn't find any options or menus related to add-ins.

Is it possible to use Office.js web add-ins in the mobile Word apps for iOS and Android? If so, how can I enable or access them in the mobile versions of Word?

I ensured that the Office.js add-in follows all the requirements and best practices outlined in the official Microsoft documentation. It loads correctly in the desktop versions of Word, and there are no issues with its functionality there. Additionally, I confirmed that the Office.js library is being loaded correctly in the mobile apps.

Comment: Word add-ins are not supported on Android. See this article for the support matrix on iOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-requirement-sets?view=word-js-1.1

Comment: @RickKirkham I understand that Word add-ins aren't supported on Android. Regarding iOS, I couldn't find info on add-in compatibility with iOS mobile devices. The documentation says its compatible with iPad(which is IOS platform only ) , so I tried accessing add-ins in the Word app on iOS mobile, but no options or menus related to add-ins were available. 
Can you confirm if this is expected for Office.js add-ins on iOS mobile? If supported, please advise on enabling add-ins in the Word app on iOS mobile.

Comment: They are not supported on iOS mobile, only iPad.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I tested this with an iPad(iOS 16.6) and the latest Word app from the Apple Store. The add-ins didn't show up. As per documentation Word API 1.1(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-requirement-sets?view=word-js-preview) require version of 1.18 for Office apps & latest version on the Apple Store is 2.75

It's possible that the add-ins aren't compatible with newer releases, preventing them from appearing on the iPad. Any solutions or insights on making Word add-ins work on the iPad Word app would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend that you ask that question at the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible to test office add-ins on mobile directly. if you want to use your add-in on mobile then you need to publish your add-in on Microsoft add-in store then you can use your add-in on mobile.